# How to know which drivers are missing on my system?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, drivers

When I install linux on my laptop, it usually installs all the drivers out of the box, recently however while doing a `pacman -Syu` part of the messages displayed were the lines:

```
...
  -> Running build hook: [block]
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
...
```

This got me thinking, how can I as a user find out which parts of my system are missing drivers? I know I can use `lspci -v` etc. to list the drivers in use, but I am specifically asking about those components such as the two above, which do not have the firmware/drivers installed, so that I can use that info to go and search on how to fix the issues.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that you will miss the firmware for those two drivers, seeing as how the corresponding devices wouldn't fit in a laptop regardless.

Comment: That is output from the fallback initramfs, and can be disregarded.

Comment: Regardless, my question is more general than those two drivers. I want to know how I can find out which components in my computer are missing drivers.

Answer (score 2):

The warning the modules may be missing firmware. Meaning the system has a module but some of its firmware is not installed which is the case for certain binary blobs or other distribution issues.

Notice the driver firmware for aic94xx here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/aic94xx-firmware/ does not have an open source license. The warning therefor is stilling you that you have modules installed for which no firmware exists and therefor no proper way to detect hardware that is compatible with it. When you get these warnings it indicates modules are installed but the current system may or may not have devices that use them.

Because drivers are actually parts of modules it gets a little involved to check a kind of driver in use per device scheme. In fact modules can depend on each other as well and some "drivers" exist in the kernel itself.

Technically bus devices notify the kernel of new devices and those devices get loaded with which ever module supports that device. The device driver than creates device nodes in DEVfs with the bus and major and minor numbers of the device but this system has major limitations. In practice one also wants automatic loading of modules as events and rules. Udev uses aliasing of the modules to the bus/device names then loads the moduels as needed and creates device files.

Using `udevadm info -a /dev/<device file>` will give information for each device already loaded. SUBSYSTEMS= being core parts of Linux in use and DRIVERS= being drivers in use. All of the names in these feilds are then used in aliases by udev in "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.alias".

As you can see it isn't as clear what devices are NOT loaded because for example a module could be loaded that supportes hundreds of devices (in the form of aliases) but was only loaded for one device.

Comment: Why is it to easy in windows? All you do is go to device manager and see all the devices with warning marks on them indicating they have been detected but have issues, like no drivers. Is there nothing like this in linux?

Comment: @sprocket12 All you do in Linux is `udevadm info /dev/*` and it provides the same information. If you plug in a USB device in Linux that does not use a standard driver it to will show up in lsusb or 'ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/' but will not have a driver. The same with pci-e devices, etc. The exact same issue come up in Windows where a device without a driver that is contained on that device will not show up. The same problem also exists that device manager does NOT list out every device the system has loaded. If you use a graphical desktop there are programs that provide similar layout.

Comment: @sprocket12 pci and usb lets call them "bus members" show up in Windows and Linux much the same way. Once their drivers are installed they might show up as several actual drivers. Comparing say does each device have at least "one" driver loaded ALSO wouldn't be accurate for that reason.

Comment: Another example is block devices on linux. Technically each block device loads a file system driver. But without the driver  to read the block device that is the physical harddrive you don't see any of those devices or their drivers. A usb device will be recognized as a device on the bus connected to a port but the fact that it provides say.. a microphone and camera won't show up until it has a driver etc. lspci + lsusb gives you as much information about devices without drivers as Windows Device Manager does. You're asking if there's an exhaustive way to do it and there kinda is sort of.

Comment: You can get something that looks like Windows Device Manager with KInfoCenter for example.